# SQL Remote query very slow after migrating sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, database-migration

I have a Sql Server 2005 express edition with one Database. I have too a C# winforms application to access to table customers that has 500 rows aprox. I have the sql server 2005 Express  inside the local pc with the winforms app.

Now I've bought a server with SQL Server 2008 standard edition and I've migrated my database to that server and reconfigured my application to access to the new server throught Lan.

The problem is that a simple query like `SELECT name, lastname,phone,fax,address FROM Customer ORDER BY name` (I have 500 rows) If I execute it in the server, it runs in 1 second but if I open my application (in other pc trought lan, not in the server)  it takes about 4 minutes to return the results.

I don't know what to do because the database is very very small.

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any testing to see what type of latency exists between your PC hosting the app and the database? Also, could you post the code from your application you're using to retrieve the data?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan for the query?

Comment: Have you tried running the app on another client pointing to the server ?

Comment: Looks like your database is accessed through the slow internet...

Comment: The latency is perfect, my lan have only for the moment 4 pc's. Yes, I've tried to run the application from the client, and from the pc I've coded it and it's still very slow. If I connect my laptop to the sql server 2005 it goes very fast. The problem is after migrating to other server with 2008

Comment: Is the query also slow through SSMS?

Comment: No, both queries from clients are from my application.

Comment: You might have a bad plan stuck with your application due to different `SET` settings. Check `sys.dm_exec_sessions` for differences in settings like `arith_abort` for the session from SSMS compared to the session from the app, then adjust the app to set those same settings before issuing the query.

Comment: I'll try today but I don't understand why SET settings has changed. Maybe a problem migrating from 2005 to 2008?

Comment: I've tried to execute my application in the server and it runs very fast. I've tried too to create another database without migrating it and insert all the rows in the new database and from clients runs very slow and the query times out.

Comment: I think that the problem is the server because if I run the query inside the server it takes less than one second, but if I run with client pc it takes 2minutes 30 seconds (to return 500 rows). I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to run a SQL Profiler and see from the trace if the query itself is actually taking 4 seconds to execute when coming from your client.

some info on how to create a trace using the profiler here:
http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Using_SQL_Server_Profiler
 and here
http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ht/trace.htm or http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2232/working-with-sql-server-profiler-trace-files/

I would guess that the query itself is probably running in the same amount of time no matter where the query is issued and the trace can help prove this.  Run the query locally, then remotely and compare the duration for each of these requests.   if the times are close you can be confident that the actual query is not at fault and you can concentrate on identifying other sources of latency - perhaps network, etc.

Comment: I'll try sql profiler but I think that the problem is the server or server's lan adapter because if I run the query in the server it takes less than one second and if I run remotely it takes 2 minutes 30 seconds. I can't find any problem at server because it downloads very fast from internet..